# generate 100 virtual ip on a single system using java

Tags: java, ip, virtualhost

I have a situation like i have to create 100 ips virtually over a single system where each ip will perform their own request response task. I have written the application of request response in java for single real ip. How can i generate 100 virtual ip on a system and bind the request-response for each ip in java?

Comment: Are you talking about virtual IP adresses? That's usually an administration job and not done from an application directly. You can *bin* to an IP adress from the application, but not create it.

Answer (score 1):

The maintenance of IP numbers is a task for the underlying operating system and there is no support for it in the standard java runtime.  Hence if you want to do this you must invoke commands directly in the same way as you would if you were to do this personably by hand, and you must be authorized to do so by the operating system.

This strongly hints that you may be using the wrong tool for the job.  Perhaps you should consider opening a new question describing what problem you really need to solve and ask for suggestions on how to design it?